# Displaying vpl.mesh_plot in PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, vtk

I need to render an .stl image on an user interface.

I created the UI with PyQt5, and I have managed to render the .stl image with vplotlib. However, I am having problems with displaying this vpl.mesh_plot on the Qframe that I have on UI (name: self.ui.MyQframe; the window does not necessarily need to be of this type, can also be QGraphicsViewer or else).

This is the function that renders the .stl image:

```
import vtkplotlib as vpl
from stl.mesh import Mesh
def setScan(self):
        path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image", "",
                                                            "stl Files (*.stl)")  # Ask for file
        mesh = Mesh.from_file(path)

        vpl.mesh_plot(path)

        vpl.mesh_plot(mesh)

        vpl.show()
```

##Edit 1:
Based on Eyllanesc's answer I changed the QFrame to QtWidget, and set fig=self.MyQtWidget in each vpl.mesh_ ... + changed show() accordingly.

However, it still opens up as a new window & I'm not sure why.

```
def setScan(self):
    path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image", "",
                                                        "stl Files (*.stl)")  
    mesh = Mesh.from_file(path)
    self.MyQtWidget = vpl.QtFigure()

    vpl.mesh_plot(path,fig=self.MyQtWidget)

    vpl.mesh_plot(mesh,fig=self.MyQtWidget)
    self.MyQtWidget.show()
```

Comment: 1) have you tested my code? If it worked for you then the problem is with your implementation. 2) If your problem is with your implementation then you need to edit your post and add the [MRE] of your attempt. that piece of code you added is not.

Comment: Note: If a QWidget is not added to a layout or a parent is not set then it will be displayed as a new window. In my solution use the first method.

Comment: Eyllanesc - Thank you so very much for your help! Adding the parent did the trick.

Comment: 1The MRE is not the same as your project (read the link for more information)

Comment: Offtopic, but - how can I change the size of the rendered mesh? Changing the size of the widget itself does not seem to do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`QtFigure`](https://vtkplotlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Figures.html#qtfigure) which is QWidget:

```
import sys

import vtkplotlib as vpl
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from stl.mesh import Mesh


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select STL")
        self.figure = vpl.QtFigure()
        vbox.addWidget(button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.figure)

        button.clicked.connect(self.select_filename)
        self.figure.show()

    def select_filename(self):
        path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, "Select Image", "", "stl Files (*.stl)"
        )
        if path:
            self.load_mesh(path)

    def load_mesh(self, filename):
        mesh = Mesh.from_file(filename)
        vpl.mesh_plot(mesh, fig=self.figure)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eyllanesc! I changed the Qframe to QWidget in my UI, let's call it self.MyQWidget for simplicity. I set self.MyQWidget = vpl.QtFigure(), and defined fig=self.MyQWidget in each of the vpl.mesh, as you showed above & added the self.MyQWidget.show(). However, it still pops up a new window whenever the button is clicked, instead of showing it in the specified figure (self.MyQWidget). What am I missing?